# PHP - Mandar los datos de entrada a una BD

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo enlazado el código PHP con el HTML y los datos se me guardan en la BD pero a la hora de dar al botón "enviar" me aparece el siguiente warning y no se muy bien que hacer ya que soy nueva.
Si cambio el útimo else (para ver si el correo o el usuario esta en uso) únicamente me entra al else, no sé si tendrá algo que ver.

***Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ()) in () on line 38 y hace un par de horas me funcionaba de forma correcta. Este es el código:***

Muchas gracias!

```
 <?php
            $servername = "";
            $username = "";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "";


            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
            $Nombre= $_POST['Nombre'];
            $Apellido= $_POST['Apellido'];
            $Usuario= $_POST['Usuario'];
            $Email= $_POST['Email'];
            $Cotraseña= $_POST['Contraseña'];
            $RepetirC=$_POST['RepetirC'];


            $sql="INSERT INTO `cuentas`(`Nombre`, `Apellido`, `Usuario`,`Email`,`Contraseña`) VALUES ('$Nombre','$Apellido','$Usuario','$Email','$Contraseña')";


            if($Contraseña!=$RepetirC) {
            echo "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
            } else {

            $checkuser="SELECT Usuario FROM `cuentas` WHERE Usuario='$Usuario'";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $checkuser);
            $RepetirCuenta = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

            $checkmail = "SELECT Email FROM `cuentas` WHERE Email='$Email'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $checkmail);
            $Repetirmail = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
            }

            if ($RepetirCuenta>0 && $Repetirmail>0) {
            echo 'El correo o el user esta en uso';
            } else {
                header("Location: login.html");
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pareciera que al final de tu script tienes la etiqueta de cierre de PHP seguida de una línea en blanco.

```
<?php
  ....código...

  if ($RepetirCuenta>0 && $Repetirmail>0) {
      echo 'El correo o el user esta en uso';
  } else {
      header("Location: login.html");
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  }
?>
<!-- línea en blanco -->
```

Esta línea constituye contenido que php enviará al browser y, cuando se envía contenido, no se puede usar `header(...)`.

Para este caso de uso, quita la etiqueta de cierre, que no es necesaria (aunque no sabemos si al algo más después de ésta que sí necesites imprimir).

---

Segundo, es sano comprobar si las variables `$_POST` están definidas. Como estás silenciando los `E_NOTICE`, ese problema pasaría bajo el radar. Podrías hacer algo como:

```
if (
    !array_key_exists('Nombre', $_POST) ||
    !array_key_exists('Apellido', $_POST) ||
    !array_key_exists('Usuario', $_POST) ||
    !array_key_exists('Email', $_POST) ||
    !array_key_exists('Contraseña', $_POST) ||
    !array_key_exists('RepetirC', $_POST)
) {
    echo 'Faltan campos del formulario';
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit();
}
```

---

Por otro lado, hay más de un flujo en donde el script se rompe. Si la contraseña no calza con "repetir contraseña":

```
   // entras acá
   if($Contraseña!=$RepetirC) {
     // se envió contenido
     echo "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
   } else {
     // No entra acá
     ....
   }

   // estas variables no existen
   if ($RepetirCuenta>0 && $Repetirmail>0) {
      // luego no entra acá
      echo 'El correo o el user esta en uso';
   } else {
      // Sino que entra acá
      header("Location: login.html");
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   }
```

Lo de arriba es equivalente a:

```
   if($Contraseña!=$RepetirC) {
     // se envia contenido
     echo "Las contraseñas no coinciden";

     // habiendo escrito "las contraseñas no coinciden..."
     // no puedes usar header(...)
     header("Location: login.html");

     // pero además ejecutas la inserción 
     // arriesgando pisar un usuario existente
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   }
```

---

Supongamos ahora el camino feliz: las contraseñas calzan y el usuario no existe, el código que se ejecuta es:

```
      header("Location: login.html");
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

No es seguro que se ejecutará la inserción. Aunque la redirección en teoría no interrumpe el flujo, estás metiendo una racing condition. Debiera ser, en cambio:

```
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      header("Location: login.html");
```

---

Otro problema: el mail existe pero el nombre de usuario no. Entonces

```
   // $Repetirmail es 1
   // $RepetirCuenta es 0
   if ($RepetirCuenta>0 && $Repetirmail>0) {
      // luego no entra acá
      echo 'El correo o el user esta en uso';
   }
```

Tendría que ser un OR:

```
   if ($RepetirCuenta>0 || $Repetirmail>0) {
      // entra acá si cualquiera de las dos es mayor a cero
      echo 'El correo o el user esta en uso';
   }
```

Pero es más eficiente:

```
   $sentencia_existe = "SELECT Email,Usuario  FROM `cuentas` WHERE Email='$Email' OR  Usuario='$Usuario'";
   $resultboth = mysqli_query($conn, $sentencia_existe);
   $ExisteUsuariooMail = mysqli_num_rows($resultboth);
   if ($ExisteUsuariooMail>0) {
     ...
   }
```

---

Y para terminar, qué pasa si mando el usuario `Amenadiel'; DROP TABLE cuentas;--`? Tu sentencia

```
   $checkuser="SELECT Usuario FROM `cuentas` WHERE Usuario='$Usuario'";
```

Ejecutará

```
   SELECT Usuario FROM `cuentas` 
   WHERE Usuario='Amenadiel'; 
   DROP TABLE cuentas;
   --'
```

Es un caso frecuente que hasta tiene su propia tira cómica en XKCD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mismo pasará en las otras sentencias que interpolan variables manualmente. La manera segura es usar [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-stmt.php).

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sentencia_existe = 'SELECT Email,Usuario  FROM `cuentas` WHERE Email=? OR  Usuario=?';

if (!$stmt_existe = $conn->prepare($sentencia_existe)) {
    printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt_existe->error);
    exit();
}

$stmt_existe->bind_param('ss', $Email, $Usuario);
$stmt_existe->execute();
$stmt_existe->store_result();

$ExisteUsuariooMail = $stmt_existe->num_rows;
$stmt_existe->close();

if ($ExisteUsuariooMail > 0) {
    echo 'El correo o el user esta en uso';
    exit();
}
```

Lo mismo con el insert:

```
$sentencia_insercion = 'INSERT INTO `cuentas`
            (`Nombre`, `Apellido`, `Usuario`,`Email`,`Contraseña`)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

if (!$stmt_insercion = $conn->prepare($sentencia_insercion)) {
    printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt_insercion->error);
    exit();
}

$stmt_insercion->bind_param('sssss', $Nombre, $Apellido, $Usuario, $Email, $Contraseña);
$stmt_insercion->execute();
$stmt_insercion->close();
header('Location: login.html');
exit();
```

Con respecto a esto:

> Si cambio el útimo else (para ver si el correo o el usuario esta en
>   uso) únicamente me entra al else, no sé si tendrá algo que ver.

Esto no se entiende. ¿Qué cambio haces específicamente?

Comment: Al final he conseguido arreglarlo utilizando sus pasos, me notificaba el fallo de header por dejar un espacio antes del <?php.También  he modificado las llamadas de mysql para que sea más eficiente y todo me funciona de forma correcta. El else también lo he conseguido arreglar, la condición del if que había hecho estaba mal formulada y no me imprimía el echo en ningún momento. Muchísimas gracias, me ha servido de grandísima ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Este error te aparece porque intentas utilizar la función `header()` después de haber enviado algún dato previo desde tu servidor web, probablemente algún mensaje de error relacionado con el acceso a tu base de datos.

Comenta el `header()` y asegúrate que el navegador no muestra nada antes de que te redirija a `login.html`

Por favor, si no te funciona lo que pruebes, modifica la pregunta añadiendo tus intentos para poder completar la respuesta.